What does こんなところ refer to here
From Kokoro chapter 24:

私は早速先生のうちへ金を返しに行った。例の椎茸もついでに持って行った。ただ出すのは少し変だから、母がこれを差し上げてくれといいましたとわざわざ断って奥さんの前へ置いた。椎茸は新しい菓子折に入れてあった。鄭寧に礼を述べた奥さんは、次の間へ立つ時、その折を持って見て、軽いのに驚かされたのか、「こりゃ何の御菓子」と聞いた。奥さんは懇意になると、こんなところに極めて淡泊な小供らしい心を見せた。

I am not certain what こんなところ refers to. I think it either refers to the situation previously described or her mannerism?

こんなところ in this context means "this type of scene" or "such situations".

奥さんはこんなところに小供らしい心を見せた。
It was in situations like this that she showed her childlike side.

